# Flexbox with margins alignment issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm running into a flexbox + margin issue that I can't quite figure out. I'm assuming it's a flex-quirk but figured I'd see if anyone else has noticed this and if any solutions exist.

In the CodePen below you'll see I have a row of buckets set to `flex: 1;` with a `margin-left: 20px;` on them.

Below that is a content area with a `flex: 2;` and `flex: 1;` and equal `margin-left: 20px;`'s as the buckets.

Both areas have a container that pulls them left 20px to offset the first margin.

[CodePen Example Here](http://codepen.io/geebru/pen/vEKzgN?editors=110)

As you'll see - the two 1/3rd's divs do not line up with the 1 2/3rds div. If you remove the margins, they all line up perfectly but margins seems to throw it off every so slightly.

If I want these to line up, will I have to find a non-margin solution?

Edit: This is the area I'm referring to specifically where you can see the mis-alignment: http://cl.ly/image/0z1z2j141V2X/Image%202014-12-19%20at%205.37.07%20PM.png

Comment: Your 3 ``bucket``s each has a 20px margin. Your ``content-left`` and ``content-right`` each has a 20px margin, but there's only 2 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margins are the issue here, resp. the “gutters” you’re placing between the boxes by those margins – because two times 1/3 of (1200px - 20px - 20px) is of course not the same as 2/3 of (1200px - 20px).

The only way I can think of spontaneously to solve this, is to use a percentage margin value instead, and use according percentages for the `flex` property of the boxes as well.

Doing away with the negative margins, using a margin of 1% each side in between, and eliminating the left margin of the first and the right margin of the last element, and `flex: 32.667%` (1/3 of 100%-2% for the margins) for the buckets and `flex:66%`/`flex:32%` for the 2/3 and 1/3 elements below (2/3 and 1/3 of 100%-1%), gives you this: http://codepen.io/CBroe/pen/YPWOJG

Comment: That's basically what my fallback system is using - does using a percentage as the flex value somewhat remove the nicety that is flex? As in, doesn't that just make it, essentially, a fluid layout?

Comment: Somewhat disregard that comment - you still get the perks of flex layout, just a bit more manual in the sizing department. I'll count this as a solution - looks good, thanks!